# Is there a way to run a command line utility from javascript?

Tags: javascript, command-line

I am designing a javascript utility which needs to grep a password file ('ypcat passwd | grep ') in Unix. PERL uses "backtick" or System to run the command line. Python uses os.system.
Is there a similar method in javascript?

Comment: explore child_process in nodejs, you can use something like : let {exec} = require("child_process"); exec("cmd")

Comment: Did you mean in node.js?  (if so, add the tag)

Answer (score 0):

Yes sir there is https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html
It's child_process.exec()

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a similar method within native JavaScript, but you may be able to achieve this using NodeJS.

Check this out,
https://nodejs.org/api/os.html